# mPDF page-break-inside avoid not working

Tags: html, mpdf, page-break-inside

Can somebody tell me why mPDF doesn't accept this code to avoid page break inside my div

```
    <div style="page-break-inside:avoid !important;">
       multi
       line
       content
    </div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors?

Answer (score 1):

may be, set in your extension mpdf -> config.php and set

> tableMinSizePriority

to be false 
  like this 
`$this->tableMinSizePriority = false;`